# introduction of capacitor http module from core stops firebase/firestore working

Tags: android, ios, firebase, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I just introduced capacitor-community/background-geolocation into a Vue3 Capacitor project. I noticed the calls to save the locations stopped firing after a few minutes [and this comment from the repo suggests that I'd need to use native http to get around this issue](https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation/issues/14#issuecomment-1293574693).

I've installed native http via capacitor and included this in the capacitor.config.ts:

```
...otherConfig,
CapacitorHttp: {
    enabled: true,
},
CapacitorCookies: {
    enabled: true,
},
```

The problem now is that none of my firebase firestore sdk calls work since making this change (they work if I remove the Capacitorhttp config item again).

I get lots of error messages like this when on android or iOS:

```
 TO JS {"url":"https:\/\/firestore.googleapis.com\/google.firestore.v1.Firestore\/Listen\/channel?database=projects%2FMY-PROJECT%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=rpc&SID=9nR2u6nG8qTh7mXxsUpXbQ&CI=0&AID=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=m5em9kc4kwhr&t=1","data":"<!DOCT
⚡️  [warn] - [2023-04-22T14:51:52.422Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.1): Connection WebChannel transport errored: [object Object]
⚡️  [error] - [2023-04-22T14:51:52.423Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
⚡️  To Native ->  CapacitorHttp request 62249784
2023-04-22 16:51:52.475173+0200 App[6009:63443] [NSURLSession sharedSession] may not be invalidated
```

I can see the "internet connection" suggestion in the error output there but that is not an issue.

I've submitted a [bug to the capacitor repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6534) but wanted to put it out there to see if anyone had any insight or direction for me to fix this?

Any ideas?

Comment: same issue. any solution?